# Error when >9 affiliations are added in PNAS (pnastwo.cls) LaTeX template

Tags: errors, templates, counters, affiliation, pnas

I ran into the following error when attempting to add more than 9 affiliations in the author list using the pnastwo.cls PNAS LaTeX template file (available here: http://www.pnas.org/site/misc/PNASTWO.CLS)

The error reads:

"LaTeX error: Counter too large"

I'd appreciate help with this issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the class uses symbols to typeset the affiliations through the kernel's `\@fnsymbol` and the kernel only provides nine definitions for the symbols used; attempting to use more than nine symbols will trigger the error given by `\@ctrerr`, i.e.,

```
! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.
```

One possible solution would be to modify `\@fnsymbol` to include more symbols (see below), or to load a package doing that for you: [`footmisc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc), for example (it extends the supply up to 16 symbols):

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage{footmisc}

\title{A}
\author{A%
\affil{1}{hhh}%
\affil{2}{hhh}%
\affil{3}{hhh}%
\affil{4}{hhh}%
\affil{5}{hhh}%
\affil{6}{hhh}%
\affil{7}{hhh}%
\affil{8}{hhh}%
\affil{9}{hhh}%
\affil{10}{hhh}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Redefining `\@fnsymbol` would be something like (adding a tenth symbol):

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}

\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{%
\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or \mathsection\or
\mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
\or \ddagger\ddagger \or \mathsection\mathsection\else\@ctrerr\fi}}%
\makeatother

\title{A}
\author{A%
\affil{1}{hhh}%
\affil{2}{hhh}%
\affil{3}{hhh}%
\affil{4}{hhh}%
\affil{5}{hhh}%
\affil{6}{hhh}%
\affil{7}{hhh}%
\affil{8}{hhh}%
\affil{9}{hhh}%
\affil{10}{hhh}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

for kernel's versions prior to 2015; the 2015 version is a little more elaborated (again I added just a tenth symbol):

```
\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{%
\ifcase#1\or \TextOrMath\textasteriskcentered *\or
\TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger\or
\TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger \or
\TextOrMath \textsection \mathsection\or
\TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph\or
\TextOrMath \textbardbl \|\or
\TextOrMath {\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}{**}\or
\TextOrMath {\textdagger\textdagger}{\dagger\dagger}\or
\TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\ddagger\ddagger}\or
\TextOrMath {\textsection\textsection}{\mathsection\mathsection}\else
\@ctrerr \fi}
\makeatother
```